# AngularJS module injector

Tags: angularjs, module

i'm new in AngularJs, ask for help:

Assumption:
First, there are 2 modules defined as below:

```
angular.module("module1", [])....;
angular.module("module2", [])....;
```

And now, as normal, we will define the main module "MainModule" which depends on module1, module2, as following:

```
angular.module("MainModule", **["module1", "module2"]**)....;
```

And my question is whether the dependencies can be declared lazy, like this:

```
var mainModule = angular.module("MainModule", **[]**)....
......
**mainModule.injector(["module1", "module2"]);**
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to do lazy declaration:

```js
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {

    var applicationModuleName = 'mainModule';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = [];

    var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {
        angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);
        angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
    };

    return {
        applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
        applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
        registerModule: registerModule
    };
})();
angular.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName,ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleVendorDependencies);

ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('module1',[]);
angular.module('module1',[]);

ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('module2',[]);
angular.module('module2',[]);
```